# Not Found (404): Resource 'guidOfMyManagedIdentityServicePrincipal' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-registration

I created an Azure function and enabled the managed identity option. It creates a new Enterprise application with a unique guid. I would like to add this managed identity as an owner of a specific AAD group. In the browser it works when I enter the managed identity guid, but when I try it by PowerShell code I get the error below:

```
Add-PnPMicrosoft365GroupMember -Identity $aadGroupId -Users $guidOfMyManagedIdentityServicePrincipal

Not Found (404): Resource 'guidOfMyManagedIdentityServicePrincipal' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add-PnPMicrosoft365GroupMember** and **Add-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwner** adds users to the **Microsoft 365** group type but here you are adding an application. I believe it only allows to add users in it.

- If you will try to add the Enterprise application which is created by enabling managed identity manually from Admin center then your application will not be visible in the search result.

[image]

[image]

- Due to this you are getting `does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present` error.

**Portal**-

If you will add the enterprise application as owner in portal directly, it will get added but it won't be visible in Admin center.

[image]

To add the owner in the portal you can use the PowerShell script `Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId "e83adea" -RefObjectId "<ManagedIdentityGuid>"` in azure function.

AFAIK, `Add-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwner -Identity "e83ad3a" -Users "UsersObjectId"` will work for Users. It works while adding an users in function app.

```
$siteUrl = "https://******.sharepoint.com"
Connect-PnPOnline $siteUrl -ManagedIdentity

Add-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwner -Identity "e8*****a3a" -Users "<user principal>"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the answer is to use this command to add the managed identity as the aad group owner? Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId "aadGroupId" -RefObjectId "<ManagedIdentityGuid>"

Comment: Yes, you can use this command. It works